# How to Disable Multiple Buttons in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton, iboutlet

How to Disable Multiple buttons at a time when one button pressed, without creating outlets foreach one in iphone?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why don't you want to create outlets for them?

Comment: Without an outlet, how do you expect to control the button?

Comment: set set tag to buttons in Xib and get object using viewWithTag option and you can perform any operation using that object

Answer (score 4):

You can set button tags for you UIButtons and for looping through each button in a view you can use the for-in loop.

```
    for (UIButton *button in self.view.subviews)
    {
        <#statements#>
    }
```

This should solve your problem and the tag to buttons can u used for referencing the buttons

Answer (score 0):

You should set YES `exclusiveTouch` property for each button. But you cannot do this in IB. So you should maybe loop through all subviews in main view and set this property for all buttons.